# Overcoming Unity IL2CPP compiler issues ("error: unknown type name")

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, accord.net, il2cpp

I'll try to be brief...

Unity 20022.3.4f1, building for Android w/ IL2CPP backend and ARM64 (for Pico VR).

imported DLL's (through nugetforunity)

1. Accord.3.8.0
2. Accord.MachineLearning.3.8.0
3. Accord.Math.3.8.0
4. Accord.Statistics.3.8.0

We are trying to build our Android project with the above DLL's, and are constantly stumped by the IL2CPP compiler with the following error:

```
[Bee] failed with output:
PROJECT\Library\Bee\artifacts\Android\il2cppOutpu\cpp\GenericMethods__21.cpp(10621,91): error: unknown type name 'Sparse_1_t2B37F496308C51B005F6B737F6DA2974891E4668'
typedef double ( *func_L_28) SquareEuclidean_t7D455591968D62E424E96927FD8DDA6231CC1501*,Sparse_1_t2B37F496308C51B005F6B737F6DA2974891E4668*,Sparse_1_t2B37F496308C51B005F6B737F6DA2974891E4668*,const RuntimeMethod*);
                                                                                                        ^
```

I have included a link.xml file next to the imported DLL folders (Assets\Packages\link.xml) which has the following contents:

```
<linker>
    <assembly fullname="Accord.3.8.0"/>
    <assembly fullname="Accord.Math.3.8.0"/>
    <assembly fullname="Accord.Math.Core.3.8.0"/>
    <assembly fullname="Accord.MachineLearning.3.8.0"/>
    <assembly fullname="Accord.Statistics.3.8.0"/>
</linker>
```

I've tried changing the stripping levels, changing the link.xml to include "preserve="all" for each of the DLL's... and I'm just not getting anywhere.

Does anyone have any idea why IL2CPP is tripping up on these DLL's?

I know that the IL2CPP compiler is finnicky, but it is necessary for us to be able to use TOBII Eye Tracking with the Pico Neo 3 eye.

As always, any and all help would be greatly appreciate.

Mike

Comment: are you sure Accord is unity compatible?

Comment: It works fine in editor and when built for windows standalone. Its just the Android compiling that causes an issue. And even then, only when using the IL2CPP backend, as opposed to Mono. But, as mentioned, we need Il2CPP for the Pico SDK.

Comment: right android and such dont use the same OS, there are differences, not every DLL in the world is compatible with all things or even unity, what works in the editor doesnt always work when built - although theres hope from the windows, but you usually have OS specificl DLLs.   So, Does Accord claim it works on android?

Comment: According to its github, Accord.net works with both Unity3D and mobile. This we know beause, as mentioned, it does build for Android using Mono. This is just an IL2CPP compiling problem.

Comment: Sounds like something their support would be best to handle

Comment: Accord.net, itself, is now archieved due to development being comlleted. Not sure there will be any help from them. Hence coming here. Helping to get help with IL2CPP from Unitys side of things.